# best practices: dynamic method execution in python

Tags: python

I'm just starting out in python after years of Java, C, c++, etc.
I have a long list of files/modules that each contain one major method that I want to call dynamically. For each keyword, I have a .py file with the name get_foo and inside each get_foo.py, there is a foo method.  So I want to pass in the command name "foo" and execute the method get_foo.foo()

I really don't want to do this with an ugly if/then/else block

```
sections = [ "abstract",  "claim",  "drawing", "examiner"]
command = "claim"
```

What I want to something like

```
exec("get_" + command + "." + command)
```

But I really don't know even which areas of exec/eval/etc do this.

Comment: Something to note here also is that unlike, say, Java, having a module to contain a single method (or class) of the same name is not really good style.  A module is a collection of components in and of itself, so it's redundant and overly verbose to have only one class or method per module.

Comment: @sr2222, are you suggesting that get_abstract() and get_claim() and get_examiner() all belong in the same source file?

Comment: I have no idea what they do without more context.  But if they are related to each other, they probably at least don't all belong in their own module.

Comment: "explicit is better than implicit": if I am reading the code and I see `command('abstract')` how much more do I need to know than if I see `foo.get_abstract()`? Python isn't Tcl and if you find yourself wanting to `eval` something, you are probably hurting readability.

Comment: If this was Java, we'd use an interface and have a get_parts() method implemented in each class that implements the interface. I don't speak enough python to even phrase the question well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`importlib` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html) to dynamically import, and `getattr()` to find your function:

```
import importlib

def call_command(cmd):
    mod = importlib.import_module('get_' + cmd)
    func = getattr(mod, cmd)
    return func()
```

Or, simply import all your modules and add them to a dict to map command to callable:

```
import get_foo, get_bar, get_baz

commands = dict(foo=get_foo.foo, bar=get_bar.bar, baz=get_baz.baz)

def call_command(cmd):
    return commands[cmd]()
```

Comment: Doesn't that make `call_command('foo')` a unnecessarily mysterious?

Comment: @msw: If that's so then *all* functions and modules are mysterious. It's called encapsulation, and it's a good tool!

Answer (score 4):

solution 1

```
from get_foo1 import foo1 # get_foo1.py in directory
from get_foo2 import foo2 # get_foo2.py in directory
foo1()
foo2()
```

can be done in other ways too

```
import get_foo1
import get_foo2

get_foo1.foo1()
get_foo2_foo2()
```

to dinamically call them you have a lot of ways too

```
commands = {"foo1":foo1, "foo2":foo2} 
# notice foo1 and foo2 have no "()" because we're referencing function and not calling it

#and then call them

commands["foo1"]()   # notice (), this means we're calling function now
```

Comment: And you could even use a combination of `os` functions and `__import__` to walk a directory and dynamically load and call the script functions.

Comment: @sr2222 I can see that. But is that a good idea? I guess its OK, but seems a bit too smalltalk-like after all these years of Java

Comment: Well, more often then not, trying to do something like that is overcomplicating the issue when really the problem is a poorly designed system.  However, the tools are there to do these sorts of things specifically because there are legitimate use cases.  Use a solution because it is the simplest, best way to solve your problem, don't reject it because it violates some "thou shalt not" type style rule.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a function which calls a function from a module:

```
def call_function(func):
    module = __import__("get_" + func)
    return getattr(module, func)()
```

Then call this function like this:

```
call_function("claim")
```

Comment: This is also a nice approach. Thanks